# Reset TP-Link TL-WR1043ND from DD-WRT to original firmware

Tags: dd-wrt, restore, firmware

I have installed this firmware since I thought it'll be faster. However sometimes it's just slower than it was, but in some cases things are much worse - for example, even Gmail fails to work.

Is it possible to recover/reinstall the original firmware? I have read steps about OpenWrt but not about DD-WRT. Should I just install OpenWrt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the latest "original" firmware from TP-Link's [Download page](http://www.tp-link.com/support/download.asp?a=1&m=TL-WR1043ND).
A utility is included whose purpose is unclear - you might try and see if it helps.

The installation instruction at this [article](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr1043nd#back.to.original.firmware) says:

> WARNING: Only perform the dd action
>   below if your original firmware has
>   the word "boot" in it, for example,
>   wr1043nv1_en_3_9_17_up_boot(091118).bin.
>   Please do not dd your original
>   firmware if it has no "boot" in its
>   name, for example,
>   wr1043nv1_en_3_11_5_up(100427).bin,
>   because if you do, you will brick your
>   router!

Comment: Yepp.. but how to upload it to the router? If I just put it to firmware upgrade, it says I cant do it like that. SO FAR, I've found this guide: http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=450943&sid=4f23da2b1774bd505e159dcba7876ce1 >> - get the original, 'cut' firmware:  >>mtd -r write filename linux .... << would this work? :/

Comment: Apparently not : see my edit. I would download the firmware and utility and see if it helps. You might need to connect the router thru a serial cable (?). Let me know how it goes.

Comment: You have a particularly troublesome router. See http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=68793&sid=662998b1ee98f72f6d5b2c578aca7976. Are you sure it won't be simpler to buy a new router?

Comment: See also this : http://www.hotspotsystem.com/deskpro/kb_article.php?ref=7389-YUDK-7658

Comment: The one I have linked fixed the issue. First I used that "cut" firmware with ssh and pendrive, and then reflashed it again with the original one. Thank you. (the first what I linked and what you your new answer is. :))

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install original firmware on my TL-WR1043ND V2. It doesn't matter if you have DD-WRT or OpenWrt, the process is the same and it's quite easy.

Basically I followed what is described in this video and article:

https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/81462

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkUc76lDbl8

Steps I did (on Windows machine):

1. Download from *official* site you firmware and save it. My was [here](https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/tl-wr1043nd/v2/#Firmware). Official files works with this technique. You don't need to strip any "boot" section or download files from some unofficial websites.
2. Download [tftpd](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/tftpd32_download.html) program
3. Plug in you laptop with ethernet cable to router.
4. Go to Controll Panel -> Network Panel -> Network and Sharing Centre -> Change Adapter settings.
5. Right click on *Enthernet* -> Properties.Then select "Internet Protocol Version 6. (TCP/IPv4)" -> Properties. And change IP address to this:
   [image]
   This 192.168.0.66 is where your router will try to find firmware when is started in recovery mode (I found some more info on polish blog ([link](https://morfikov.github.io/post/jak-przy-pomocy-trybu-recovery-odzyskac-router-tp-link)) but you can probably find more info how it works if you want)
6. Open Tftpd64 program, click "Browse" and select the folder where you extracted firmware file
7. Now turn off router.
   8 Press reset button and power button. You can release the power button but keep pressing reset button.
   9 You should see some "logs" in Tftpd64 program in "log viever" tab like

```
Connection received from 192.168.0.86 on port 4084 [26/04 21:40:57.616]
Read request for file <wr1043v2_tp_recovery.bin>. Mode octet [26/04 21:40:57.618]
File <wr1043v2_tp_recovery.bin> : error 2 in system call CreateFile The system cannot find the file specified. [26/04 21:40:57.620]
Connection received from 192.168.0.86 on port 4084 [26/04 21:40:59.605]
Read request for file <wr1043v2_tp_recovery.bin>. Mode octet [26/04 21:40:59.605]
File <wr1043v2_tp_recovery.bin> : error 2 in system call CreateFile The system cannot find the file specified. [26/04 21:40:59.617]
Connection received from 192.168.0.86 on port 4084 [26/04 21:41:01.610]
Read request for file <wr1043v2_tp_recovery.bin>. Mode octet [26/04 21:41:01.617]
File <wr1043v2_tp_recovery.bin> : error 2 in system call CreateFile The system cannot find the file specified. [26/04 21:41:01.617]
Connection received from 192.168.0.86 on port 4084 [26/04 21:41:03.617]
Read request for file <wr1043v2_tp_recovery.bin>. Mode octet [26/04 21:41:03.617]
File <wr1043v2_tp_recovery.bin> : error 2 in system call CreateFile The system cannot find the file specified. [26/04 21:41:03.618]
```

Notice the name of .bin file that the router was searching for. Mine was `wr1043v2_tp_recovery.bin`. Change the firmware file name to this name In my case I changed `wr1043v2_en_3_19_32_up_boot(150910).bin` to `wr1043v2_tp_recovery.bin`

10. Turn off router and turn on again with reset button pressed. You should see in Tftpd program that router is copying you firmware.

[image]

When you see it just release reset button

11. Just wait for router to install firmware
12. Revert ip changes you did in step 5.
13. Go to http://192.168.0.1/ and login with default credentials (admin/admin)

Answer (score 0):

Get the "Webrevert to Stock" file at the download page of the latest dd-wrt firmware for your router model and pay attention to hardware version, "upgrade" using this file in dd-wrt will restore to stock tp-link firmware and you can update with the latest stock firmware again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient but today I was able to finally roll back from DD-WRT v24SP2- (03/25/13) to the latest TP-Link original firmware on my TP-Link TL-WR1043ND v1.8 after a lot of effort.

What worked for me was to roughly follow the back to original firmware part here: https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr1043nd#back.to.original.firmware with two small caveats:

1. I had to use a thumb drive to get the firmware into the device
2. The MTD partition for me was 'linux' and not 'firmware' as
   described on the instructions there.

The firmware I downloaded had the 'boot' word in it so I had to remove the boot loader from it.

In order to figure out which was the right MTD , I matched the size of the firmware after trimming the boot loader with the size of the MTD, which I could peek as follows:

```
root@DD-WRT:/tmp/mnt/sda_part1# cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00020000 00010000 "RedBoot"
mtd1: 007c0000 00010000 "linux"
mtd2: 00620000 00010000 "rootfs"
mtd3: 000b0000 00010000 "ddwrt"
mtd4: 00010000 00010000 "nvram"
mtd5: 00010000 00010000 "FIS directory"
mtd6: 00010000 00010000 "board_config"
mtd7: 00800000 00010000 "fullflash"
```